# How to create half circle multi progress bar in react native

Tags: react-native, progress-bar, react-native-svg-charts

I have a requirement to create a half circle multi progress bar like this

[image]

This is what I have achieved so far with the library react-native-svg-charts using this code

```
        <View style={{marginTop: hp('5%')}}>
          <ProgressCircle
            style={{height: 320}}
            progress={0.3}
            progressColor={'rgb(134, 65, 244)'}
            startAngle={-Math.PI * 0.5}
            endAngle={Math.PI * 0.5}
            strokeWidth={30}
            cornerRadius={0}
          />
        </View>
```

[image]

The problem is that this is a single progress bar, how could I add multiple progresses in it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what libraries like https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-progress do?

Comment: A simpler way could be to look for ways of using react-native-svg programmatically, this is a good use case imo